# How to change the Google Chrome default print margins

Tags: google-chrome, printing, margins, print-preview

In Chrome, the default print margins are narrow. I would like the default to be wider.

Is there a way to make them wider?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a way to change the default print margins in Google Chrome. It is possible in Google Chrome version 22 and further versions.

While in current and previous versions of Chrome it is not possible, **[starting in Chrome 22 the selected printer and its settings should persist across browser restart.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123741#c8)**

---

In order to change Chrome default print margins, all you'll have to do is change the margins settings to your preference and it will become the default print margins.

To change the print margins settings in Google Chrome, this is what you'll need to do:

- Enter the Chrome print preview page (Shortcut: Ctrl+P):

[image]

- There is a sidebar in the left side of the print preview page, with
  several printing options, including `Margins` settings.
- You can change the margins to `None`, `Minimum` or `Custom`. To
  change the margins to your preference (in your case making them
  wider), choose `Custom` and adjust the margins as you wish (by stretching them).

Keep in mind that in Google Chrome versions prior to version 22, when printing with `Custom` margins, Chrome will remember those settings and use them again next time you print. However, if you close and reopen Chrome, the margins revert back to the default of 0.4 inches.

---

Another way to change the default print margins in Chrome, is to [enable kiosk mode printing](http://support.vendhq.com/entries/21006382-enable-kiosk-silent-printing-for-google-chrome-on-windows-video) and use the following code to change the margins settings to your preference (for no margins at all, use `0px`):

```
@page{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Try using `cm` instead of `px`: `@page { margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; }`

Comment: Doesn't matter which unit is used if the value is 0 - but when it's 0, there's no need to include the unit at all!

Comment: Note that kiosk mode no longer seems to be a requirement to use @page, as long as Margins is set to Default in Chrome's print settings.

Comment: simply use this: @page { margin: 0 }