# Selecting margin when printing in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When printing in Google Chrome, if text is enlarged, a part of the text is cut off.
I read that you can stretch the margins in Preview, but I couldn’t find where or how.

Answer (score 1):

@amiregelz gave a great answer in another question, which answer also will solve your question:

> There is a way to change the default print margins in Google Chrome.
>   It is possible in Google Chrome version 22 and further versions.
>
> While in current and previous versions of Chrome it is not possible,
>   **[starting in Chrome 22 the selected printer and its settings should persist across browser restart.](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123741#c8)**
>
> ---
>
> In order to change Chrome default print margins, all you'll have to do
>   is change the margins settings to your preference and it will become
>   the default print margins.
>
> To change the print margins settings in Google Chrome, this is what
>   you'll need to do:
>
> - Enter the Chrome print preview page (Shortcut: Ctrl+P):

[image]

> - There is a sidebar in the left side of the print preview page, with    several printing options, including `Margins` settings.
> - You can change the margins to `None`, `Minimum` or `Custom`. To    change the margins to your preference (in your case making them
>     wider), choose `Custom` and adjust the margins as you wish (by
>     stretching them).
>
> Keep in mind that in Google Chrome versions prior to version 22, when
>   printing with `Custom` margins, Chrome will remember those settings
>   and use them again next time you print. However, if you close and
>   reopen Chrome, the margins revert back to the default of 0.4 inches.
>
> ---
>
> Another way to change the default print margins in Chrome, is to
>   [enable kiosk mode printing](http://support.vendhq.com/entries/21006382-enable-kiosk-silent-printing-for-google-chrome-on-windows-video) and use the following code to change
>   the margins settings to your preference (for no margins at all, use
>   `0px`):
>
> ```
> @page{
> margin-left: 0px;
> margin-right: 0px;
> margin-top: 0px;
> margin-bottom: 0px;
> }
> ```

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/457861/how-to-change-the-google-chrome-default-print-margins)